# Insert date into wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to insert date into a wpdb, it fetches name and comment from a form but I cant get todays date to work, it all works if I exclude the date, what am I doing wrong?

```
global $wpdb;
$name = "";
$comment = "";
$current_date = date("YY-mm-dd");


$wpdb->insert ( $table_name, array( "name" => $_POST["name"], "comment" => $_POST["comment"], "date" => $_POST["$current_date"]));
```

Comment: Remove the `$_POST` reference `$wpdb->insert ( $table_name, array( "name" => $_POST["name"], "comment" => $_POST["comment"], "date" => $current_date));`

Comment: @AaronW. Ok that actually does work BUT I now get 3 new rows in my database, any way around that?

$wpdb->insert ( $table_name, array( "name" => "name", "comment" => "comment", "date" => "$current_date"));

Comment: Based on your code it shouldn't be adding 3 new rows.  You'll need to add more details and update your code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain your date format but I think this work for you
it will give you today date like "2016-05-20" or if you want you can add hour to format like "2016-05-20 23:33:52"

and please change this

```
"date" => $_POST["$current_date"]
to
"date" => $current_date
```

only today date

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
```

with time

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```